# Converting a specific date to the local short date format

Tags: vb.net

In our application, we build date selection menus based on month end dates that are determined programmatically. In the US, a date might be 12/31/2012. In France, it might be 31/12/2012 or it could be a slightly different format that I get from CultureInfo.

My question is this: If I have a string date such as 12/31/2012 that is generated by the application - how can I format it properly for the culture the application is being run in? I can't convert the string to a date and then format it, because I don't know ahead of time what culture the application is being run in and what constitutes a valid date. Am I going to have to parse the short date format to try to display the date properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't convert the string to a date and then format it, because I don't know ahead of time what culture the application is being run in

Yes, you can. You can both parse it to a `DateTime` and format it using the current culture.

VB.NET:

```
Dim myDate As DateTime 
             = DateTime.Parse("12/31/2012", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim cultureAwareShortDate As String =
             = myDate.ToString("d", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture)
```

C#:

```
var myDate = DateTime.Parse("12/31/2012", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var cultureAwareShortDate
             = myDate.ToString("d", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture);
```

Comment: There's also the .ToShortDateString() method, which just uses the culture associated with the current thread, no need for any arguments to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the application would generate the date as a DateTime instead of a String. Then you don't need to use the conversion which Oded shows as the first step.